# For a real and symmetric matrix M, if I take $M_1 = |M|$, is the relation $M_1 = M_1^T$ true?

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-science

I am implementing a fast Manhattan Frame estimation method based on this [paper](https://eprints.whiterose.ac.uk/183320/6/A%20Fast%20Manhattan%20Frame%20Estimation%20Method%20based%20on%20Normal%20Vectors.pdf).

A crucial step to this algorithm is computing the real, symmetric $\mathbf{M}$ matrix parameterized by 15 variables as shown in the following screen shot

[image]

According to the paper, $\mathbf{M}$ must be a real, positive semi-definite matrix as Equation 29 of this paper states

$\mathbf{M} = \mathbf{Q} * \mathbf{D} * \mathbf{Q^T}$ where eigenvalues $\lambda_k \geq 0$ and $\mathbf{Q}$ is an orthogonal matrix

However, trying with a number of surface normal datasets, I end up getting matrix $\mathbf{D}$ of the following form

$ \mathbf{D} = \begin{pmatrix}
-d_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -d_2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & d_3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & d_4 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & d_5 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & d_6 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$

As you can see, this implies $\mathbf{M}$ is positive, symmetric indefinite matrix.

To mitigate this problem, one idea I have is to form $\mathbf{M_1} = |\mathbf{M}|$. Here $|\mathbf{M}|$ implies taking element-wise absolute value so that $ m_{ij} \in \mathbf{M_1} \geq 0$

My question is $\mathbf{M_1} = \mathbf{M_1^T}$ true for all cases?

A screenshot of how $\mathbf{M}$ and $\mathbf{D}$ came out from one of the surface normal dataset is shown below

[image]

Comment: 1) The paper you mention is behind a paywall... As a consequence, the connection between a "Manhattan Frame" (all normals are in one among 3 directions ?) and the big matrix is somewhat mysterious. 2) Have you attempted to write a program with this matrix and take random values for its 15 variables and ask for the eigenvalues (easy to do in Python for example) ? If all of them are $\ge 0$, the authors of the paper should be right.

Comment: @JeanMarie thank you very much for your prompt reply.  The paper is accessible, I had found that open source link but mistakenly provided another one. I am updating the question with the open source link.

Regarding coding, I have implemented in C++ upto Equation 29 and am using surface normals calculated from a real dataset. I am a bit skeptic about the random method since if you take a look at Equation 19, the 15 variables are defined as a function of the elements of the surface normal vectors. Is there a way I can condition the M matrix instead?

Comment: The first expression $\frac{1}{n}\sum A_i^TA_i$  can be written $A^TA$ where the $A_i$ are the columns of $A$. And this matrix is semi-definite positive. Besides what is the meaning of the (lowerset) $a_i$ ?

Comment: @AzmyinMd.Kamal What exactly do you mean by $|M|$? For any of the usual definitions, it is clear that $M = M^T$ implies that $|M| = |M|^T$, so perhaps you have some unusual definition in mind. Do you mean to ask where $M$ being positive definite implies that $|M|$ is positive definite?

Comment: @AzmyinMd.Kamal Assuming no errors in the paper, the $-d_1, -d_2$ that you obtained on the diagonal are close to zero and probably arose as numerical artifacts; otherwise, their statement that $M$ is positive semidefinite would necessarily be false. I think that you can proceed by simply setting $d_1$ and $d_2$ equal to zero.

Comment: @BenGrossmann no $d1$ and $d2$ are not close to zero, on the contrary they appear to be the largest eigenvalues (if they were positive). To illustrate I have edited the question and provided a screen shot of the $\mathbf{D}$ that I got from one of my tests

Comment: @AzmyinMd.Kamal Again, please explain what you mean by $|M|$

Comment: @JeanMarie each $a_i$ is a $R^3$ vector representing a unit directional vector. The way i understand it, these vector represents what direction, a face of an object is pointing at from the perspective of an observer

Comment: @AzmyinMd.Kamal Regarding the result you've added, that's strange. If we assume that the paper has no errors, then you must have made a mistake in computing $M$ or in computing this decomposition. Can you confirm that $QDQ^T$ matches the original $M$? Can you confirm that you have correctly implemented Equation (20)?

Comment: @BenGrossmann thank you very much for the idea. One way I checked if Equation (20) was correctly implemented, was performing $\mathbf{M} = \mathbf{M^T}$ test using this command

```bool isSymmetric = M_mat.isApprox(M_mat.transpose());```

I didn't try a reverse check of Equation 29 though. I assumed the eigen decomposition method in Eigen C++ was working correctly since the eigen values computed by the library matched up with MATLAB`s answer. Doing the reverse check now

Comment: @Azmyin One "debugging" step I would try here is to calculate $M$ using the $\frac 1n \sum A^T(a_i)A(a_i)$ formula rather than using the right hand side (which may contain an error). Matrices computing using this summation formula will necessarily be positive semidefinite, as long as none of the $A(a_i)$ have complex number entries. Incidentally, is there any way that you might have complex number entries?

Comment: @BenGrossmann to the best of my knowledge, no there cannot be complex numbers

Regarding my $| \mathbf{M} |$ I meant was taking element-wise absolute value. I will add this point to the question for clarity

Comment: @Azmyin Something must have gone wrong with the computation of $M$ (or its formula in the paper): the 5,5 and 6,6 are negative, but positive semidefinite matrices cannot have negative diagonal entries.

Comment: @AzmyinMd.Kamal To answer the question about $|M|$: it is clearly true that if $M$ is symmetric, then so is $M$. If $m_{ij} = m_{ji}$ (for all $1 \leq i,j \leq 6$), then it surely follows that $|m_{ij}| = |m_{ji}|$. Interestingly, it is possible for $M$ to be positive definite and also have $|M|$ fail to be positive definite. For an example, consider the matrix 
$$
M = \pmatrix{10 & 3 & -2 & 1\\
3 & 10 & 0 & 9\\
-2 & 0 & 10 & 4\\
1 & 9 & 4 & 10}
$$
(example taken from Horn and Johnson's *Matrix Analysis*).

Comment: @BenGrossmann thank you very for the clear counter example. I was afraid of that. Regarding the pointers with $(5,5)$ and $(6,6)$ I am going to investigate and get back to you. 

Regarding whether $\mathbf{Q} * \mathbf{D} * \mathbf{Q^T}  == M$, Yes, when I do the reverse check, I get matrix M back exactly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per the suggestion by @BenGrossmann, the problem with $\mathbf{M}$ matrix lied with the (5,5) and (6,6) elements. Solving this issue did not require me to use $\mathbf{M_1} = |\mathbf{M}|$.

Regarding the question, I am accepting the comment by @BenGrossmann on the original problem is $\mathbf{M_1} = \mathbf{M_1^T}$ true for all cases where $\mathbf{M_1} = |\mathbf{M}|$ given $\mathbf{M}$ is real and symmetric as **No** as at least one counter example exsists where $\mathbf{M_1}$ was shown to fail positive (semi)definite test.